# "Duplicated securities submitted"; applying api calls through a small dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rblpapi

I'm trying to find some codes for a few securities currently stored in a dataframe.

Frame is of the following pattern:

```
tibble [1x 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
$ Bloomberg Code: chr [1:6] "BondISIN1" "BondISIN2" "BondISIN3" "BondISIN4" "BondISIN5" "BondISIN6"
```

I want to feed these codes into a API call so I can find their BB ids as follows (bds has also been tried):

```
bdp(df$`Bloomberg Code`,"ID_BB")
```

I this and received:

```
Error: Duplicated securities submitted.
```

I tried:

```
for(isin in 1:length(df$`Bloomberg Code`)){
  thing[[isin]] <- bdp(df$`Bloomberg Code`, 
               'ID_BB', 
               overrides = periods[isin, ]
               )
}
```

And got the same issue. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the best way to do it is by:

```
bdp(unique(df$`Bloomberg Code`), "ID_BB")
```